# python 2.7 ignores default encoding set in sitecustomize.py when parsing scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I’m having problems getting python 2.7 to read scripts containing utf-8 strings; setting the default encoding to utf-8 in sitecustomize.py doesn’t seem to take.

Here’s my sitecustomize.py:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

I can verify that the default encoding has been changed from the command line:

```
$ /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'
utf-8
```

However, when I try to run a script containing a utf-8 string, as in test.py below (containing · at code point U+00b7)…

```
filename = 'utf-8·filename.txt'
print(filename)
```

…the default encoding seems to be ignored:

```
$ /usr/bin/python test.py 
  File "test.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file test.py on line 1, but
no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Using an [encoding declaration](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations), as in test-coding.py below…

```
# coding=utf-8
filename = 'utf-8·filename.txt'
print(filename)
```

…*does* work:

```
$ /usr/bin/python test-coding.py
utf-8·filename.txt
```

Unfortunately, the problem’s come up with scripts that are generated and run by another program (the catkin build system’s catkin_make). I can’t manually add encoding declarations to these scripts before catkin_make runs them, giving *SyntaxError & check PEP 263*. Changing the default encoding seems like the only solution short of going deep under catkin’s hood, or eliminating all non-ascii paths on my system… and setting it in sitecustomize.py should work, but doesn’t.

Any ideas or insights greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you setting the default encoding **at all**. You should not do that. Rather, fix your Unicode handling code to not rely on a default encoding.

Comment: Besides, the system default encoding is never used for source files. That's a hardcoded default.

Comment: I'd rather use the encoding declaration, but the scripts are generated and run by another program (the catkin build system’s catkin_make). I can’t manually add encoding declarations to these scripts before catkin_make runs them.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")` is not doing what you think it is doing. It has no effect on how Python parses source files. That's why you are still seeing SyntaxErrors when the source files use non-ascii characters. To eliminate those errors you need to add an encoding declaration at the beginning of the source file, such as

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

---

Regarding `sys.setdefaultencoding`:

Do not try to change the default encoding. The default encoding is used when Python does silent conversion between str
    and unicode. For example,

Expected Python2 behavior:

```
In [1]: '€' + u'€'
```

should raise UnicodeDecodeError because Python tries to convert `'€'` to unicode by
    computing `'€'.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())`

If you change the default encoding, you get different behavior:

```
In [2]: import sys; reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
<module 'sys' (built-in)>

In [3]: '€' + u'€'
u'\u20ac\xe2\x82\xac'
```

If you change the defaultencoding, then your Python's behavior will be different than just about all other people's expectation of how Python2 should behave.

Comment: You’re right, and I’d rather put the encoding declaration in the files, but the scripts are being generated and immediately used by another program, *catkin_make*. Short of hacking up my own version of catkin_make, I can’t put it in there before the script fails to run.

Comment: Here is a [similar bug report](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/476). I think you may need to discuss your problem with the catkin developers in order to resolve it cleanly (without hacking catkin).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the default encoding for source files. That default is hardcoded, as part of the language specification.

Set the [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html) header instead, as the interpreter is instructing you to do. You'll have to fix the Catkin build system, or rewrite the files it produces to include the header. Simply add a first or second line to those files with `# coding=utf8`, a task easily accomplished with Python.

The system default encoding is *only* used for implicit encoding and decoding of Unicode and byte string objects in running code. You should not try and change that, as other often relies on the value to not change. The ability to set it was removed entirely from Python 3.

Comment: It sounds like there’s no way to implicitly say “treat all files like they say _# coding=utf8_”, which is a shame. Thanks!

Comment: @HonoreDoktorr Python 3 will do that, but that also requires changes in syntax.